# Bootstrap Grid with Flexible Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm using bootstrap to create a grid with items. The problem is they will often have different heights and I would like them to flow beneath each other.

I tried using this example from bootply but it chops of the bottom of one box to fill the space in the next column.

```
<div class="col-md-4 whats-on-card card">
</div>

/*STYLES*/
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


.row {
 -moz-column-width: 17em;
 -webkit-column-width: 17em;
 -moz-column-gap: -1em;
 -webkit-column-gap: -1em; 

 }

 .whats-on-card {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:  0.25rem;
  padding:  1rem;
  width:  100%; 
 }
```

http://www.bootply.com/85739

My example is here
http://www.allaboutus.ie/whats-on/

Basically if the solution I have worked except without chopping the boxes...

Is this possible with CSS & Bootstrap?

Comment: your bootply link is not working.

Comment: appears it's not - anyway - you'll see the same thing at the other link

Comment: @CiaránHanrahan take a look at the grid system options. You could try using the Fluid container, or you can add in the .col-xs-6 class with the .col-md-4 class.  The column ordering might help the cause, too.